# Inserting input elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to insert/move some insert elements on a form on an internal site.

I am using jquery and the .insertafter function but although the labels will move the inputs wont

This works to move the labels

```
$("label[for='rn_SelectionInput_26_Incident.CustomFields.c.need_written_reply_1']").insertAfter("label[for='rn_SelectionInput_26_Incident.CustomFields.c.need_written_reply_0']")
```

but the inputs wont

```
$('#rn_SelectionInput_26_Incident.CustomFields.c.need_written_reply_1').insertAfter('#rn_SelectionInput_26_Incident.CustomFields.c.need_written_reply_0');
```

I have also tried to hide them this also fails

```
$('#rn_SelectionInput_26_Incident.CustomFields.c.need_written_reply_1').hide()
$('#rn_SelectionInput_26_Incident.CustomFields.c.need_written_reply_0').hide()
```

I have a fiddle here if anyone can help
http://jsfiddle.net/kxLsp4ne/

Comment: You're going to have problems if your id contains `.` - this is a class selector as in `<div id="d" class="class1">` `$("div.class1")`  or `$(".class1#d")` is the same as `$("#d.class1")` so $("#rn_SelectionInput_26_Incident.CustomFields.c.need_written_reply_1") will not find an element with `id=#rn_SelectionInput_26_Incident.CustomFields.c.need_written_reply_1`

Comment: **Always test your selectors** - add `console.log($('#rn_SelectionInput_26_Incident.CustomFields.c.need_written_reply_1').length)` (==0)

Comment: You *could* use the same format as your `label[for]` but I *strongly* recommend you fix your IDs:  `$("div[id='rn_SelectionInput_26_Incident.CustomFields.c.need_written_reply_1']").hide()`

Answer (score 0):

in the end the solution was simple

```
$('#rn_SelectionInput_26_Incident.CustomFields.c.need_written_reply_1').insertAfter('#rn_SelectionInput_26_Incident.CustomFields.c.need_written_reply_0');
```

Thanks for the help